# How to import a class from a python file in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm currently using django and putting python code in my views.py to run them on my webpages. There is an excerpt of code that requires a certain class from a python file to work sort of like a package but it is just a python file I was given to use in order to execute a certain piece of code. How would I be able to reference the class from my python file in the django views.py file? I have tried putting the python file in my site packages folder in my Anaconda3 folder and have tried just using from [name of python file] import [class name] in the views.py file but it does not seem to recognize that the file exists in the site packages folder. I also tried putting the python file in the django personal folder and using from personal import [name of file] but that doesn't work either

Comment: What is *the django personal folder*? If you put the file in the same directory as the `views.py` as `filename.py`, `from .filename import Class` should be sufficient.

Comment: have you tried put the python file within the same folder along with you view.py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply put the `mypythonfile.py` in the same directory of your `views.py` file. And `from mypythonfile import mystuff` in your views.py

Comment: will python file still be recognizable and executable  if we upload the web app on server ?

Comment: yes it will @user13505457

Answer (score 12):

Every views.py file belongs to an app in django created as:

```
django-admin startapp my_app
```

so your views.py file is in my_app folder.
If your custom python file is in the same folder you can simply do:

```
     from my_app.custom_file import ClassName  # Don't forget to update app name
```

or

```
from .custom_file import ClassName  # Don't forget to update app name
```

If your python file is in another app folder then update the app name respectively.