# How to import custom modules in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-import

I have a module created with the name metrics.py . I want to use this module in my views.py file.The command i used to import is "import metrics" in views.py file. both views.py and metrics.py are in the same folder. i am getting this error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'metrics'"

How to use the custom module i created in views.py

Comment: Try `import .metrics` (note the dot)

Comment: not worked showing invalid syntax

Comment: `from . import metrics`? Or put the whole path to the models, e.x. if `metrics` is in `path/to/metrics`, try `from path.to import metrics`

Comment: Thank you so much "from . import metrics" worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a class from a python file in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576350/how-to-import-a-class-from-a-python-file-in-django)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.